# Loading of json files from S3 to sparkR dataframe

Tags: sparkr

I have jason files saved in S3 bucket.  I am trying to load them as dataframe in spark R and I am getting error logs.  Following is my code.  Where am I going wrong?

```
devtools::install_github('apache/spark@v2.2.0',subdir='R/pkg',force=TRUE) 

library(SparkR)

sc=sparkR.session(master='local')

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"="xxxx", 
       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"= "yyyy", 
       "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"="us-west-2")


movie_reviews <-SparkR::read.df(path="s3a://bucketname/reviews_Movies_and_TV_5.json",sep = "",source="json")
```

I have tried all combinations of s3a , s3n, s3 and none seems to work.

I get following error log in my sparkR console

17/12/09 06:56:06 WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
17/12/09 06:56:06 ERROR RBackendHandler: loadDF on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0):

For me it works

```
read.df("s3://bucket/file.json", "json", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Ankit said should work, but if you are trying to get something that looks more like a dataframe, you need to use a `select` statement. i.e.

```
rdd<- read.df("s3://bucket/file.json", "json", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")
```

Then do a `printSchema(rdd)` to see the structure of the data. 
If you see something that has `root` followed by no indentations to your data, you can probably go ahead and select using the names of the "columns" you want. If you see branching down your schema tree, you may have to put a `headers.blah` or a `payload.blah` in you select statement. Like this:

```
sdf<- SparkR::select(rdd, "headers.something", "headers.somethingElse", "payload.somethingInPayload", "payload.somethingElse")
```